# Why is Hive metastore host failing to load mysql connector?

Tags: mysql-connector, ambari, hdp

HDP-3.1.5.0 / Centos 7

I configure the connector on the metastore host (I have also done on the Ambari manager host)

```
# ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23-1.el7.noarch.rpm
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Setup ambari-server
Copying /lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23-1.el7.noarch.rpm to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23-1.el7.noarch.rpm
Creating symlink /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23-1.el7.noarch.rpm to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/mysql-connector-java.jar
If you are updating existing jdbc driver jar for mysql with mysql-connector-java-8.0.23-1.el7.noarch.rpm. Please remove the old driver jar, from all hosts. Restarting services that need the driver, will automatically copy the new jar to the hosts.
JDBC driver was successfully initialized.
Ambari Server 'setup' completed successfully.
```

But still, see this when trying to start the metastore

```
Underlying cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
```

Comment: Your metastore server doesn't have the mysql jar on its classpath

Comment: I placed the rpm under $HIVE_HOME/lib which I thought resulted in it being available on the classpath. I am obviously wrong.

Comment: Java doesn't read classes from RPM, only JAR or `.class` files

Answer (score 0):

You're using an RPM, not a JAR

From HDP documentation

> `--jdbc-driver`
> Should be the path to the JDBC driver **JAR file**

You need to use `yum` to install the RPM, which should extract the JAR somewhere on disk, and then you can symlink it to `/usr/lib/mysql-connector.jar`, for example, where it's in a defined location